# greenDAO update and updateInTx not working

Tags: android, greendao, greendao3

I'm using greenDAO 3.1 for one of my projects. Since I needed my id to be `UUID` I've decided to store it as `ByteArray`. Now the problem is I can't update my entities using `update` or `updateInTx` method and I have to use `insertOrReplace` or `insertOrReplaceInTx` method.

Can anybody tell me what is going on and why can't I update using `update` methods?

Is there any downside to using `insertOrReplace` methods instead of `update` methods?

This is my `Entity`'s schema code:

```
Entity book = schema.addEntity("Book");

book.addByteArrayProperty("id").columnName("_id").primaryKey();
book.addStringProperty("title");
book.addByteProperty("edition");
book.addStringProperty("authors");
book.addStringProperty("desc");
book.addStringProperty("pic");
```

And here's my update code:

```
BookDao bookDao = daoSession.getBookDao();

List<Book> books = bookDao.loadAll();
for (Book book : books)
    book.setDesc("It doesn't really matter!");

bookDao.updateInTx(books); //This isn't working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trouble I found the reason.

Since you can't query `BLOB` type in `sqlite` and since `update` methods use a condition over `id` in `WHERE` clause, the `update` method won't find the record I'm looking for. On the other hand when I use one of `insertOrReplace` methods, since the `id` field is unique it can't insert redundant `id` to the table and it completely replaces the old record with the one I'm trying to update. So, there was no problem with `update` methods, the real problem is with using `ByteArray` as `id`.

For the same reason, I also encountered an error when selecting using `load` method.